# Rack ssl not working with Thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, https, thin

I installed rack ssl for Rails 3.07 per these instructions: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/

It is not working. The first https request (for the login page) is made and the page is served securely, but when you login it redirects to a non-secure http URL.

I am running Thin server. Does it work for Thin? What about Webrick?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you check if the the `HTTPS` parameter is present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Thin, you can pass your SSL information in using the following options:

```
$ thin --help

SSL options:
    --ssl                        Enables SSL
    --ssl-key-file PATH          Path to private key
    --ssl-cert-file PATH         Path to certificate
    --ssl-verify                 Enables SSL certificate verification
```

If you would like to configure Webrick to use SSL, [this](http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/chris_rohr/configuring_webrick_to_use_ssl.html) article from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640993/how-do-you-configure-webrick-to-use-ssl-in-rails-3) question seems to work.