# Force SSL using Thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, thin

I recently installed Thin on our server.
Now my customer asked me to implemet SSL on my whole application. So i've searched the web for a guide to implement SSL.
I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125663/rack-ssl-not-working-with-thin), which seems to be very easy.
I got my certificate and the key and i started up the server as shown. The Server starts up without any problems, but when somebody tries to connect i get this error message:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
>     what():  Encryption not available on this event-machine
>   Aborted

The Server stops and the browser shows a "Connection reset" Page.
I looked around and some people say that this has something to do with the libssl not being installed, so i looked inside the /usr - Folder and there she is.

Then i searched for other Solutions, but most of them seem to require Apache or Nginx, which is not an Option, sadly.

Any Ideas how to get Thin to work with SSL?

More Info to the System:

VHost Debian 6 x64
Rails 3.2.8
Ruby 1.8.7
Thin 1.4.1

Comment: Which command are you using to start thin?

Comment: Im using thin start -p 2048 --ssl --ssl-key-file ./my_key.key --ssl-cert-file ./my_cert.crt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i fixed this issue by just doing an update.
I begged our admin to install RVM and finally he allowed me to do so, but the problem:

I've noticed some things by reading the patch notes of Ruby since 1.8.7.
It seemed that Ruby had some issues with SSL that were fixed with Ruby 1.9.x.
Now i am running Ruby 1.9.3 with Rails 3.2.8 and everything works fine!