# How can I have a clean output with thin and ssl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, thin

I use Rails 3.0.x and I have a problem with thin output.

When I use:

```
rails server thin
```

Thin displays a list of handled requests, and logs them, almost exactly as webrick does. This is great, however I didn't find any way to use Thin in ssl mode with this command.

To use Thin in ssl mode, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125663/rack-ssl-not-working-with-thin), I use the following command (plus arguments for ssl):

```
thin start --ssl ...
```

With this command, the log is still good but Thin does not output anything in standard output.

So I tried:

```
thin start --trace
```

But now Thin writes all request *and all responses*(!) in standard output, including javascript, images, etc.

**With Thin in ssl mode, is there a way to output all handled requests, as webrick does?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When launching Thin with the command:

```
rails server thin
```

The possible options are propagated from Rack to thin in Rack::Server#start:

```
server.run wrapped_app, options
```

But in Rack::Handler::Thin#run, we can see that the handler doesn't use those options:

```
 module Rack
  module Handler
    class Thin
      def self.run(app, options={})
        app = Rack::Chunked.new(Rack::ContentLength.new(app))
        server = ::Thin::Server.new(options[:Host] || '0.0.0.0',
                                    options[:Port] || 8080,
                                    app)
        yield server if block_given?
        server.start
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When using Thin in ssl mode via the command line:

```
thin start --ssl
```

Options are parsed in Thin::Runner#parser and then used in Controllers::Controller#start

I would suggest to monkey patch Rack::Handler::Thin#run with a content similar to Controllers::Controller#start.

The result would be something like this:

```
  module Rack
    module Handler
      class Thin
        def self.run(app, options={})
          app = Rack::Chunked.new(Rack::ContentLength.new(app))
          server = ::Thin::Server.new(options[:Host] || '0.0.0.0',
                                      options[:Port] || 8080,
                                      app)
          server.ssl = true
          server.ssl_options = { :private_key_file => PATH_TO_KEY_FILE, :cert_chain_file => PATH_TO_CERT_FILE }
          yield server if block_given?
          server.start
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you please link this to the source code on github? I can't seem to find it on there.