# Rails application (localhost) automatically redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, https

I've been playing with HTTPS in a local rails application using the 'answer' from the following question: [Configuring WEBrick to use SSL in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189920/configuring-webrick-to-use-ssl-in-rails-4)

So i was running rails via a 'second /bin/rails_temp file and the https was working

now going back to my original rails file and just running 'rails s' I get redirected to https for everything

I've tried clearing cache in browsers, loading new browsers, removing /tmp/ contents

Totally lost!

Comment: do you have `config.force_ssl = true` in you application or environment file?

Comment: did you add any rack middleware or any before_actions in application controller?

Comment: I havent made any changes to my application.rb no

Comment: You were right in the first case, I just hadnt removed caches properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you forcing SSL anywhere in your application?

For example `config.force_ssl = true`

Perhaps changing the port would affect the behaviour?

`:Port => 3000,    # Specify the port here`

Perhaps your laptop is caching the state of the server so changing it's address (using `/etc/hosts`) would help?

```
127.0.0.1 sslapplication.local
```

Comment: It was infact your first point (thanks @IuriG. also) in my applications.rb and then removing all my caches and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this helped me
[Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984708/are-you-trying-to-open-an-ssl-connection-to-a-non-ssl-puma)

On your browser, click on "More tools" -> "Clear Browsing Data"

I'm using Google

Answer (score 0):

If you're using chrome:

- `Right Click on the reload icon`

then hit

- `Empty cache and hard reload`

[image: screenshot of hard rel]