# Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?

Tags: puma

After working on getting a new project to work, I found that for some reason I couldn't start my rails server. I kept getting the following error:

`HTTP parse error, malformed request: #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails. Are you trying to open an SSL connection to a non-SSL Puma?>`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this problem by clearing my browsing history, cookies and saved images.

Click ...
More tools
Clear Browsing Data

Delete everything since the beginning of time.

Comment: What is the core issue here though? Clearing files/images didn't work for me.

Comment: @Alien The core issue is that your browser is trying to access to <https://>localhost:3000 instead of <http://>localhost:3000 cause you surely already try to access to the https one.