# Why there is no "always allow" option in Firefox when using `getUserMedia`?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'm using `getUseMedia` function in my app. Every time I open Firefox permission popup appears. There is no `always allow` option.

[image]

According to the Bugzilla the feature is already implemented at `Firefox 30` - current version is `43`.

I'm using `getUserMedia` like this:

```
    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia);
```

Is it right? Why I can't select `allow always` option?

Comment: Somewhat related, [Navigator.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) is deprecated. Use [MediaDevices.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Comment: I added `mediaDevices.getUserMedia` as second option like `navigator.getUserMedia ||
        mediaDevices.getUserMedia ||
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||`, but then the browser returns `No web audio support in this browser!` error. How can I use the function?

Comment: Can't help you there, you're gonna have to wait for someone else to drop by.

Comment: in chrome, only pages served under HTTPS are allowed to persist that perm, not sure about FF, but it might be the same deal... localhost uses HTTP (no "S")

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, I configured to use https by following post, then I could choose `allow always` option! http://stackoverflow.com/a/22878130/1536527

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you seem to have discovered, Firefox, like Chrome purposefully disallows this functionality without HTTPS.

Mozilla's tests are a great source for answers around desired behavior, in this case: ["'Always Allow' ignored and not shown on http pages"](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/test/general/browser_devices_get_user_media.js#855)