# Unicorn in Heroku? Why not in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just installed the unicorn gem and added the config file under config/unicorn.rb

I also added a Procfile that looks like this:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

I am wondering, why is my localhost not running in Unicorn even if I have added this? Where is it said that this should just run in Production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't load the `unicorn` gem in your `GemFile`, Rails will default to `WebBrick`

We use [`Thin`](http://rubygems.org/gems/thin) in development, and here is our GemFile:

```
group :development do
    gem 'thin'
end

group :production do
    gem 'puma'
    gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end
```

You may also benefit from this question: [Why would I want to use unicorn or thin instead of WEBrick for development purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890529/why-would-i-want-to-use-unicorn-or-thin-instead-of-webrick-for-development-purpo)