# SSL Webrick on localhost not hosting ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, localhost, webrick

How do I get Ruby On Rails Webrick to work with self-signed SSL certificate on localhost just to test https ?
Basically, Ived followed the work that has been done here:
[Configure WEBrick to use automatically generated self-signed SSL/HTTPS certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165854/configure-webrick-to-use-automatically-generated-self-signed-ssl-https-certifica)

And produce the script like the following:

```
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'

cert_name = [
  %w[CN localhost],
]

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 8000,
                                 :SSLEnable => true,
                                 :SSLCertName => cert_name)


# Shutdown gracefully on signal interrupt CTRL-C
# http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-trap
trap('INT') { server.shutdown }

server.start
```

When I tried to access https://localhost:8000/, it did warn about trust but just went ahead, instead I had nothing come out but this. BTW, https works fine, just it seems its not getting the right route for SSL.

```
Not Found

`/' not found.
WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.2/2014-05-08) OpenSSL/1.0.2 at localhost:8000
```

console prints this:

```
[2015-07-25 23:38:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=6765 port=8000
[2015-07-25 23:38:32] ERROR `/' not found.
localhost - - [25/Jul/2015:23:38:32 MYT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 284
- -> /
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your server is returning that 404 is because the script you've set up is just for an empty WEBrick server; it doesn't actually mount your Rails app. The thread you linked to seemed to be using that script just as a minimal test for the SSL functionality. The full answer to getting WEBrick to work with SSL looks to be answered here: [How do you configure WEBrick to use SSL in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640993/how-do-you-configure-webrick-to-use-ssl-in-rails)

However, I wouldn't recommend you bother. WEBrick is strictly meant as a development-only server, and isn't suitable for use in production (which is why it's hard to get it to do things like use SSL). Instead, either set up [nginx as a SSL-serving proxy to your app](http://shiny-bits-of-code.tumblr.com/post/4749553253/ssl-proxy-with-nginx) or use a server which supports SSL easily, like [thin does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16395695/5154683).