# Install SSL certificate in Ruby On Rails with Ubuntu 14.04 environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, ssl-certificate

I would like to install SSL certificate on a site based on Ruby on Rails framework and the operating system used in the machine is Ubuntu 14.04

I have tried to install it like PHP based side but the Ruby is not using Apache, it is using webrick. I have researched a lot on Stackoverflow and other sites but did not find any reasonable answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you configure WEBrick to use SSL in Rails 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640993/how-do-you-configure-webrick-to-use-ssl-in-rails-3)

Comment: I have seen but we are using rails 4 and that was based on old version of os.

Comment: Did you even read the answer on that question? It starts with *"Tested on Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1.1"*. Your OS doesn't matter, as far as I can see.

Comment: Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640993/how-do-you-configure-webrick-to-use-ssl-in-rails?lq=1